# Euro currency formatter in iOS moves symbol before/after number

Tags: ios, swift, currency

I have a currency formatter for euros in my app. When the user initially sets it to euros from whatever other currency, the formatter displays it as `€1000`. When the app is restarted however it changes it to `1000 €`, and sometimes it even ends up as `€1000 €`! Any idea what's going on here?

```
func formatAsCurrency(currencyCode: String)  -> String? {
    let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    let isWholeNumber: Bool = floor(self) == self
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = isWholeNumber ? 0 : 2
    currencyFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = isWholeNumber ? 0 : 2
    currencyFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: currencyCode)

    if let currencyString = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(self) {
        return currencyString
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Creating an `NSLocale` from a currency code (such as GBP) won't return a valid locale by the way. See `NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()` for supported identifiers

Comment: I pass in `en_GB` or whatever locale identifier i need. it's just badly named from when i actually did pass through GBP at one point (which caused me some odd issues). Thank for pointing it out, i'll fix it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As lgor said, you want to use `currencyCode` rather than `locale`... Does this work as a replacement?

```
extension Double {

    /// Formats the receiver as a currency string using the specified three digit currencyCode. Currency codes are based on the ISO 4217 standard.
    func formatAsCurrency(currencyCode: String) -> String? {
        let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
        currencyFormatter.currencyCode = currencyCode
        currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = floor(self) == self ? 0 : 2
        return currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(self)
    }
}

300.00.formatAsCurrency("GBP")      // "£300"
129.92.formatAsCurrency("EUR")      // "€129.92"
(-532.23).formatAsCurrency("USD")   // "-$532.23"
```

---

It's also worth pointing out why you are seeing strange formatting behaviour when you modify the `locale`. By changing the `locale`, the formatter is applying different formatting rules based on that localisation.

Usually, you want to leave the locale set to its default value (`NSLocale.currentLocale()`), that way the format of the string will be localised to the users language. This is usually for things like [differences in decimal and thousand separators](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

If you specifically want numbers formatted in a specific way, then you should override the locale to ensure things are kept consistent. If you worry about what separators are being use, what currency symbol is used or there the symbol is placed in the string then be sure to set the locale to something specific or make sure that you override all the relevant properties on `NSNumberFormatter`.

For example, if I know that I want my numbers formatted to the American English locale then I would use the `NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")` to ensure that it doesn't differ. If you don't mind it being a bit more personal for your users then don't bother specifying a locale.

Comment: I've actually just changed mine to this :) the problems i was having were due to manually adding the currency symbol in one case. This also caused the problem I experienced before which is why I moved away from a currency code in the first place!

Comment: Yeah i'm going back to using locale.. using currency code it formats it as `US$1,000`. I just want $

Comment: It's not a great idea to store currency values as a `Double` if you want precision.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that different countries display Euros in a different way. There is no format for "Euro". There is a German currency format, and a French currency format, and an Italian currency format, and so on, and they all display Euros differently.

Answer (score 0):

use currencyCode/internationalCurrencySymbol properties for currencyFormatter

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/currencyCode

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-number-formatters.html

Comment: That introduced other problems for me when switching between currencies - in some cases it ended up as £S$... I've fixed my issues though. Turns out in one case the symbol was being added manually incorrectly rather than using the formatter